# What is the purpose ApplicationDbContext Class in (under IdentityModels.cs file) ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: .net, model-view-controller

I have seen this `ApplicationDbContext` class in identity models.cs in mvc Template and I am not understanding exactly what is the purpose of this class and how it works. Please shed some light on that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about an asp.net-mvc-5 application: For the default templates, `ApplicationDbContext` is used for all the ASP.NET Identity database CRUD operations.

If you don't know whats an Entity DBContext is, consider reading [this guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj729737.aspx).

Comment: In the link ,ApplicationDbContext is not discussed?

Comment: yes but, ApplicationDBContext  inherits from IdentityDbContext which in turn inherits from DbContext, the logic is the same.